# Язык и фреймворк для desktop приложений (красивый UI)

Tags: gui, ui

На каком языке и с помощью каких фреймворков сейчас пишут UI для desktop приложений

Есть необходимость написать относительно небольшое приложение, типа учетная система для договоров. Вот думаю сейчас на чем писать.

Сам знаю python, немного ruby, java, C#
База данных не принципиальна
Возможно потом нужно будет переносить на Linux
Желательно хорошо поддерживаемые библиотеки

Задача создать красивый UI (с поддержкой тем)
Желательно простота в разработке (JAVA + SWING – ИХМО ужасны, с точки зрения написания кода)

Comment: А чем не устраивает 1С?

Comment: не ищем легких путей )))

Answer (score 3):

Лучший выбор для C# - WPF. Красота, темы (через стили), MVVM-подход.

Только с Linux беда

Comment: "Возможно потом нужно будет переносить на Linux" - автор как бы сам сказал это=)

Comment: Возможно - это может быть и 0.01%, и просто автору самому (не заказчику) так хочется и еще много чего:). Для Windows-only WPF - моя любовь.

Comment: Если есть вероятность, то нельзя сжигать мосты. Даже если это 0.01%. Но раз он об этом написал, то думаю вероятность больше.

Comment: ну в конце концов Mono есть

Comment: Mono не поддерживает WPF

Answer (score 2):

[QT](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt) C++ очень рекомендую.

Вроде бы есть QT c python.

Comment: Не только есть, но еще и считается некоторыми лучшим портом Qt на другой язык. Называется эта штука PyQt.

Answer (score 2):

> Цитата
> Называется эта штука - PyQt.

Не только, я (в связи с условиями лицензии) предпочёл PySide - по сути то же самое, синтаксис 1 в 1, но лицензия мягче=)

И да, советую C++ c Qt, недавно Qt5 релизнулось. Если ближе питон, то тогда PyQt или PySide.

Comment: за PySide спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Java FX  посмотрите